# How do I make and Authenticated Curl request ("-u key:secret") from Google Apps Script?

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, urlfetch

How do I convert the following Curl command to Google Apps Script? Thank you

```
curl -u keyid:keysecret https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance?asset=ETH
```

I've tried the following but I'm getting a 401: Unauthorized error

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = "https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance?asset=ETH";
    var key = "key";
    var pass = "pass";

    try{
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, auth=(key, pass));
    }catch(err){
      Logger.log(err)
    }
    var text = response.getContentText();
    Logger.log(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've found a solution

```
function test(){
    var USERNAME = 'key';
    var PASSWORD = 'pass';
    var API_URL = 'https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance?assets=ETH';

    var authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD);
    var options = {
      headers: {Authorization: authHeader}
    }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_URL, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}
```